# Show that $x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$ is a primitive polynomial over $Z_2$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, polynomial-rings

I am new to polynomial rings and have to solve the following question:

> Show that $x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$ is a primitive polynomial over $Z_2$.

I was trying to use this theorem to solve the problem:

> A polynomial of degree $n$ over the finite field $GF(2)$ (i.e., with coefficients either $0$ or $1$) is primitive if it has polynomial order $2^n-1$.

But I am still stuck, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The theorem immediately answers the question, because $7 = 2^3 - 1$. Or is the question about how to prove the theorem?

Comment: I dont think order of plynomial is same as degree in finite field

Comment: I see, I read too quickly. What is the definition of order?

Comment: @JairTaylor The order of an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ over a finite field is the order of any one of its zeros in the multiplicative group of the appropriate extension field. Equivalently, the smallest integer $m$ such that $f(x)\mid x^m-1$. The latter definition works for any (possibly reducible) polynomial with a non-zero constant term, and makes sense in some contexts, where the former fails (because the order of a root of a reducible polynomial may depend on the choice of root).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that the polynomial $f = x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1$ does not have any (non-constant) factor of degree $\leq 3$.

This can be achieved by proving two statements:

1. show that $f$ has no root in $\Bbb F_{2^2}$;
2. show that $f$ has no root in $\Bbb F_{2^3}$.

The first can be shown by verifying that $\gcd(f, x^{2^2} - x) = 1$, and similarly the second with $\gcd(f, x^{2^3} - x) = 1$.

Computations of the $\gcd$'s are carried out with the usual Euclid algorithm.

---

One may also compress the two computations into one, by showing that $f$ has no root in $\Bbb F_{2^6}$, hence it suffices to compute $\gcd(f, x^{2^6} - x)$.

This is not necessarily simpler, as the exponent gets bigger.

Comment: what theorem did you use? Why is the first line sufficient?

Comment: If it decomposes into a product of two polynomials, then the sum of the degrees is $7$, so at least one factor has degree $\leq 3$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the why the statements 1,2 imply that there is no such decomposition and why those gcd imply the statements?

Comment: @Thomas These are basics on finite fields. For example, if $f$ had an irreducible factor of degree $2$, then the roots of that factor would generate the unique degree $2$ extension of $\Bbb F_2$, namely $\Bbb F_{2^2}$, hence $f$ would have a root in $\Bbb F_2$. The roots of the polynomial $x^{2^2} - x$ are exactly all elements of $\Bbb F_{2^2}$, hence by showing the $\gcd$ is $1$, we confirm that $f$ has no root in $\Bbb F_{2^2}$. Reference could be [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) or any standard textbook on finite fields.

Comment: Why is the first line sufficient? Because the group of nonzero elements of the field with $128=2^7$ elements has order $127$, obviously a prime. Thus *every* element different from $1$ is a primitive element, all $126$ of them. So if you find an irreducible polynomial of degree seven over $\Bbb F_2$, its roots all will be primitive elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @WhatsUp I think that this only proves that f is irreducible, Can you please elaborate How is it proving that f is primitive too ?

Comment: @njjw See the comment of Lubin above.